# How can I locate and kill file sharing sessions for open files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When we push changes out to file shares, occasionally a user will leave an application open, which in turn keeps a file open from the share - it's locked and we cannot replace it. I would like to find the sharing sessions corresponding to such files and kill them (this is read-only stuff, mainly .DLL files) in a PowerShell script before overwriting the files.

This is identical to locating the files that are open in the Shared Folders MMC, then closing the corresponding sessions there, but I need to do it programatically, and remotely, for multiple servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine Users Accessing a Shared Folder Using PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795679/determine-users-accessing-a-shared-folder-using-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything other than the new Powershell 4.0/Win2012 cmdlets, so I wrote my own script, I thought it was worth sharing:

```
# Use "net files" to get the ID's of all files and directories on this computer 
# that are being accessed from a network share.
$openFiles = net files | 
    where { $_ -match "^(?<id>\d+)" } | 
    foreach {
        # Use "net files <id>" to list all information about this share access as a key/value list, and 
        # create a new PSObject with all this information in its properties.
        $result = new-object PSObject
        net files $matches["id"] | 
            where { $_ -match "^(?<key>.*[^\s])\s{2,}(?<value>.+)$" } | 
            foreach { 
                Add-Member -InputObject $result -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $matches["key"] -Value $matches["value"] 
            }
        return $result
    }

# Now that we know everything that's being accessed remotely, close all that 
# apply to our application folder.
$openFiles | 
    where { $_.Path -like "C:\MySharedFolder\MyApp*" } | 
    foreach { net files ($_."File Id") /close }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [net file /close](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_file.mspx?mfr=true)?

Comment: Is there a way to do that remotely for a bunch of machines, other than tricks like psexec or PowerShell remoting?